# Can I dispose multiple Objects in a single go?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, parameters, ref

I have a class Instance which implements IDisposable interface like shown below.

```
class Instance : IDisposable
{
    //something
    void Dispose()
    {
        //Disposes something
    }

}
```

Now in the actual code I have few instances of the Instance which requires to be disposed in the Finally block like below

```
 finally
        {

            if (inst1 != null)
            {
                inst1.Dispose();
                inst1 = null;
            }

            if (inst2 != null)
            {
                inst2.Dispose();
                inst2 = null;
            }

            if (inst3 != null)
            {
                inst3.Dispose();
                inst3 = null;
            }

        }
```

So every-time I wanted to Dispose, I have to write the above lines for every single object.

I felt I could use 'params' keyword to reduce the no. LOC (lines of code) like below

```
   static void DisposeInstance(params Instance[] instances)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
        {

            if (instances[i] != null)
            {
                instances[i].Dispose();
                instances[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and pass instances in a single shot like,

```
 DisposeInstance(inst1, inst2, inst3);
```

But the above function would dispose only the local copy of the Instance and do not exactly dispose the actual objects(instances).

So my question is, if there is any way that I can achieve my goal of disposing objects in a single go and reduce the LOC.

Also can I use 'ref' keyword along with 'params'( which I know gives a compilation error), but somehow mixing these two to get the outcome?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There is no need to set objects to null. It will be [optimized away by the JIT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2004/12/01/273144.aspx) anyway.

Comment: why not just scope the objects, using a `using` statement? (`using (var thingy = new Instance()) { /* Do stuff ... */ }`

Comment: _"But the above function would dispose only the local copy of the Instance and do not exactly dispose the actual objects(instances)."_ **wrong**; `Dispose()` is a method that is called on the object it self. It has nothing to do from what reference it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the objects to null, and with C# 6 you can use the Null-Propagation syntax:

```
inst1?.Dispose();
inst2?.Dispose();
inst3?.Dispose();
```

This reduces the noise considerably.

Comment: This looks good! But currently I'm using.NET 4.5.1, C# 5 and VS 2013. SO is there any better way through which I can do both : Dispose and setting objects to null with lesser lines of code?

Comment: @pradeeppradyumna Not really (if you really do need to set the references to null).

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit list to your method

```
   static void DisposeInstancies(List<Instance> instances)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
        {

            if (instances[i] != null)
            {
                instances[i].Dispose();
                instances[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

So:

```
DisposeInstancies(new List<Instance> {inst1, inst2, inst3});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx) which will dispose the object automatically. Something like this:

```
using (MyClass inst1 = new MyClass())
using (MyClass1 inst2 = new MyClass1())
using (MyClass2 inst3 = new MyClass2())
{
    // code 
}
```

> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that
>   use resources should release them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's
>   resources.

Answer (score 0):

> But the above function would dispose only the local copy of the Instance and do not exactly dispose the actual objects(instances).

It disposes the object (or at least it calls the method `Dispose()`), but it doesn't set the reference to null in the caller scope. Actually only a *copied value of the reference* is set to null in `DisposeInstance` scope.

Do you really need to set it to null? If your goal is to avoid errors due to multiple call to `Dispose()` then you should use a boolean to control the state:

```
private bool hasBeenDisposed ; 

public void Dispose() 
{
    if (!hasBeenDisposed)
    {
        DisposeInstance(inst1, inst2, inst3);
        hasBeenDisposed = true ; 
    }
}
```

In addition, you should change DisposeInstance args to `IDisposable []` for reusability and readability.

```
static void DisposeInstance(params IDisposable [] instances)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
    {

        if (instances[i] != null)
        {
            instances[i].Dispose();
            instances[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little thing about dispose.

When disposing an object you clear the object of large content objects. You simply orphan the content of the object you're disposing, so that they are free to be picked up by the GC.

If you don't have any large objects or arrays in the object you want to implement IDisposable on then you don't really need to dispose it. If you need the space in memory then just null it to force it out of scope and into GC.

(There is a corner case here, GC stops your program to collect so if you have many small objects then disposing them when you have "time" is a nice way to go and remember to suppress GC after disposing them)

Disposing is kindof a judgment call you as the developer make. In most cases you don't really need it, in multiple cases its nice to have for disposing objects containing larger arrays/collections.

So for your problem, i would recommend that you dispose when you are finished with the class and not wait until the end of the "scope", alternatively place them in a list and dispose them later.

```
Queue<IDisposable> toDispose = new Queue<IDisposable>();
private void DisposeObjects(){
    while(toDispose.Any()){
        toDispose.Dequeue()?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[MSDN: Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx)